# Data Set for Quantile Regression in Survival Analysis

Tags: medical

I am new to Open Data SE and to Survival Regression: I must prepare an essay about using Quantille Regression in Survival Analysis and I have no idea which data would be proper. I think that when I want to use Quantille Regression this data should have particular structure. Could anyone recommend a specific data set?